# Why doesn't mt_rand work insided of a method?

Tags: php

I am working on a string randomizer method in php. Outside of the method, everything happens normally. Inside of the method, however, I get the following error:

```
Warning: mt_rand() [function.mt-rand]: max(0) is smaller than min(1) in /home/content/44/10902444/html/makepage.php on line 14
```

The code for the method is:

```
function roll()
{
    $dir = "s/";
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
        $pick = mt_rand(1, strlen($validChars));
        $charPick = $validChars[$pick-1];
        $dir .= $charPick;
    }
    return $dir;
}
```

I am calling it like this:

```
$url = roll();
while(is_dir($url))
{
   $url = roll();
}
```

As I Java programmer, I know that I am doing something wrong. Just not what that is ;) Any help is much appreciated and thank you in advance to anyone who responds!

**EDIT:** I know that there is a scope issue, therefore I moved the declaration of `$validChars` into the method. I am still getting an error though:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/44/10902444/html/makepage.php on line 20
```

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: Where is $validChars initialized inside a function? It's empty?

Comment: You have a scope issue, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$validChars` is not defined in the first run of for loop. Therefore the length of `$validChars` variable is 0. You effectively call:

```
mt_rand(1, 0)
```

This function call results in the notice you posted.

**EDIT:**

This code works:

```
function roll($validChars)
{
            $dir = "s/";
            for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
            {
                $pick = mt_rand(1, strlen($validChars));
                $charPick = $validChars[$pick-1];
                $dir .= $charPick;
            }
            return $dir;
}

$validChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_.";
echo roll($validChars);
```

Comment: Outside of the method it is $validChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_.";

Comment: then you will need `global $validChars;` at the top of the function

Comment: PHP does not work this way. You can solve the problem by adding a new  parameter called `$validChars` to the definition of `roll` function.

Comment: okay, I used your fix MartyIX but I'm getting an error when I call it like this:
    $url roll($validChars);